# Git submodules inside a subtree?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

As I understand it correctly, the .gitmodules file must be placed in the root of a repository.

The problem is I need to subtree another repository with submodules inside this repository, which will not work because of different reasons (merge conflicts in .gitmodules, multiple .gitmodules files etc).

How do you handle this?

Comment: https://imgflip.com/i/5b5kex

Comment: `git submodule` and `git subtree` shouldn't be mixed together. In your case you can only use submodules.